# How can you detect if a youtube video does not have a thumbnail and only uses the default image?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube API to retrieve videos but I would like to exclude results which are using the default (gray) image as a thumbnail. Being that the uploader did not select a thumbnail?

What would be the best method to do this? As I don't think there is a flag in the data to reflect this.

I'm using v3 of the youtube api.

Thanks.

Comment: It appears that videos with the "Gray" image no longer exist on youtube, removed for one reason or another, copyright or owner removed it.

Comment: There are no methods for being able to check on the status of a video that I know of. You would have to run the search again which originally pulled the video to see if it is no longer returned. Is there a method for checking on the status?

Answer (score 0):

On a recent project, I found a hacky but useful way to get relevant thumbnails for each video from the YouTube API.

Of the thumbnails each video record returns, it appears that the fourth thumbnail in the JSON is reliably an identifying frame of the video.

Below, in my fetch_movie_history method, I save the fourth movie thumbnail's url to my movie record so that I can display it later.

```
def fetch_movie_history

  watch_history = self.youtube_client.watch_history
    watch_history.videos.each do |video|
      movie = Movie.find_or_create_by(unique_id: video.unique_id)
      movie.title = video.title
      movie.description = video.description
      movie.url = video.player_url
      movie.thumbnail = video.thumbnails[3].url
      movie.save
      self.movies << movie
    end
end
```

This is an example screenshot (before styling) of a thumbnail I used on my page:

[image: example of thumbnail from fourth record in YouTube API JSON]

The description at the bottom is from the video record returned by the API, so you can see it matches up nicely with the thumbnail.

Hope this helps! Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I found another solution. I implemented a node service to read the image headers and compare the size to the size of a "no-image" image, thus removing the record when found from my database.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. I implemented a node service to read the image headers and compare the size to the size of a "no-image" image, thus removing the record when found from my database.